Villain trying the capture children? Kind of a Tim Burton feel?
A movie I recall watching as a kid, a dark film however I think it was quite family friendly. A villain trying to capture some kids, cant remember how many children there were, maybe 2 or 3. The kids were siblings. From what I can remember the villain had a kind of clown look to him, im not sure. At one point he intends to marry the eldest child but fails.
In the end he is forced to endure the trials the kids had to go through while running from him. For example I remember him having to balance on the wreckage of a house over a sea cliff, or something like that. 
Any help is appreciated.

When you were a kid; when was that? 5 years ago? 10 years ago?

Pretty much a duplicate of this.

I believe this is  Series of Unfortunate Events. Here is the Wikipedia plot, mentioning the marriage and having to go through all the trials.
And here's the trailer. It kinda look like Burton:




Yes that is it, thanks.

Please Mark my answer correct. Thanks!

Maybe you watched Chitty Chitty Bang Bang. The two children Jeremy and Jemima will be catched by the "Child Catcher". Take a look at the photos on IMDb to refresh your memory. The villain is Baron Bomburst who lives in Vulgaria where children are forbidden. But actually the villain tries to get his hands on the "famous flying car" which is the reason why the children and their father travel to Vulgaria.

OP already marked Series of unfortunate events as the right answer..

Oh, sorry. the dude should really have marked the correct answer in the proper way.

Welcome to Movies & TV (http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). You might want to elaborate a bit more on your answer to provide additional information and differentiate it from the already accepted answer
